# <f:ajax> not working in JSF 2.0 when used with HTML 5 <fieldset>

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, fieldset

Ok, I'm facing a weird error in the Ajax call from JSF page.

We are using HTML5 / JSF 2.0 .

This is the problem :

Assume that I have a class called '**MyController**' which has a '**sendEmail**' method in it.

So, in the XHTML page, I write this code

```
 <h:inputText id="Email" required="true" value="#{backingBean.email}" >
    <f:validator  validatorId="EmailValidator"></f:validator>
 </h:inputText>

<h:commandLink value="Request Number" id="requestnumber" class="button">
    <f:ajax execute="Email" 
    listener="#{myController.sendEmail}" render="Email emailmessage"></f:ajax>
</h:commandLink>
```

Request Copied from Firebug :

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/enroll/setuplogin.xhtml?
Address=Mirza%20Ghalib%20Street&
Answer1=a&
Answer2=aa&
Answer3=a&
City=Kolkatta&
CompanyName=Vinoth%20Kumar&
ConfirmPassword=Abcd_1234&
Country=1&
Email=a%40mk.com&
FirstName=Vinoth&
FourDigitPin=1234&
LastName=Anderson&
MobilePhone=3423432444&
OfficePhone=3423432444&
Password=Abcd_1234&
Question1=1&
Question2=2&
Question3=9&
State=Warsaw&
TimeZone=1&
UserName=vinoth&
accountsetupform=accountsetupform&
javax.faces.ViewState=-1878625446915184180%3A-5994619738596437588&
javax.faces.behavior.event=action&
javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&
javax.faces.partial.event=click&
javax.faces.partial.execute=requestcodebutton%20Email&
javax.faces.partial.render=Email%20emailmessage&
javax.faces.source=requestcodebutton&
postalCode=2344&
verifycode=
```

**So this works fine**.

But when I put it inside `<fieldset>` tag for HTML5, it does not work. It's an application wide problem. Wherever I use `<fieldset>`, the Ajax call does not call the controller at all. Using `<fieldset>` is the only difference here.

```
<fieldset>
<legend><h:outputText value="MyValue" /> </legend>
<h:inputText id="Email" required="true" value="#{backingBean.email}" >
    <f:validator  validatorId="EmailValidator"></f:validator>

    </h:inputText>  

    <h:commandLink value="Request Number" id="requestnumber" class="button">
        <f:ajax execute="Email" 
            listener="#{myController.sendEmail}" render="Email emailmessage"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandLink>
   </fieldset>
```

**This does not work.**

When I inspect the Response in firebug, this is what I get

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
      <partial-response>
         <error>
            <error-name>
               class java.lang.IllegalStateException
           </error-name>
           <error-message>
               <![CDATA[Parameters processing failed.]]>
           </error-message>
          </error>
     </partial-response>
```

*Request copied from firebug*

```
  http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/enroll/setuplogin.xhtml?
  =undefined&
  =undefined&
   =undefined&
  =undefined&
  =undefined&
  Address=Mirza%20Ghalib%20Street&
  Answer1=d&
  Answer2=d&
  Answer3=d&
  City=Kolkatta&
  CompanyName=Vinoth%20Kumar&
  ConfirmPassword=Abcd_1234&
  Country=1&
  Email=a24232332%40mk.com&
  FirstName=Vinoth&
  FourDigitPin=1234&
  LastName=Anderson&
  MobilePhone=3423432444&
  OfficePhone=3423432444&
  Password=Abcd_1234&
  Question1=1&
  Question2=8&
  Question3=10&
  State=Warsaw
  TimeZone=1&
  UserName=vinoth&
  accountsetupform=accountsetupform&
  javax.faces.ViewState=-6971358458957395852%3A-7032811866036542714&
  javax.faces.behavior.event=action&
  javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&
  javax.faces.partial.event=click&
  javax.faces.partial.execute=requestcodebutton%20Email&
  javax.faces.partial.render=Email%20emailmessage&
  javax.faces.source=requestcodebutton&
  postalCode=2344&
  verifycode=
```

**The only difference I find the the request parameters is that, the one doesn't work has some 'undefined' in it.**

I have tried many things.It's not working. Apparently we need to use `fieldset` here.

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Which jsf version are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to include HTTP request payload for both cases.

Comment: @BalusC - I have added the HTTP Request for both the cases.

Comment: Request parameter without a name is causing this exception. Clearly, some JavaScript is doing it wrong while preparing the ajax request. Which JSF impl/version exactly are you using? Please don't say "JSF 2.1", this is merely a spec version. There are Mojarra and MyFaces impls which each also have their subversion like "Mojarra 2.1.26". With the right impl name and its version, we can lookup the right source code files and bug reports. And, are you loading any custom JS files such as jQuery, Modernizr, etc? What if you disable them all?

Comment: @BalusC  JSF Version  - Mojarra 2.1.7. Also we have included jquery from Primefaces 3.5 (<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />). We don't really use primefaces tags in this page though.

Comment: @BalusC - I tried running the code after removing the Jquery and Primefaces. Still the same result.